# Java generics: capture cannot be applied to Object

Tags: java, generics

I have code that has a `Map` of (Message)Handlers. I'm trying to make the handlers generified (as seen by the interface Handler). Without generics the handlers all need to cast from Object to the respective class, which would be nice to avoid (but everything works). For each message class (`Foo` below) I have a handler class.

How can I keep a Map of any kind of Class to any kind of Handlers and get/call with "just" an `Object`? (the parameter to `handleMessage(Object)` can't be restricted)

See MWE below.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Logic
{   
    Map<Class<?>, Handler<?>> handlers = new HashMap<Class<?>, Handler<?>>();

    public void run()
    {   
        handlers.put(Foo.class, new FooHandler());
    }   

    public void handleMessage(Object msg)
    {   
        Handler<?> handler = handlers.get(msg.getClass());
        if (handler != null) {
            handler.execute(msg);
        }   
    }   

    private interface Handler<T>
    {   
        public void execute(T msg);
    }   

    private class FooHandler implements Handler<Foo>
    {   
        public void execute(Foo msg) {}
    }   

    private class Foo {}
}
```

This code produces:

> Logic.java:16: execute(capture#x of ?) in Logic.Handler cannot be applied > to (java.lang.Object)
>               handler.execute(msg);

How can this be repaired to work while still keeping the Handler interface generic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't define the relationship between the key and the value in a field, but you can use accessor methods to enforce it, provided only these methods are used to access the map.

```
private final Map<Class, Handler> handlers = new HashMap<Class, Handler>();

public <T> void addHandler(Class<T> clazz, Handler<T> handler) {
    handlers.put(clazz, handler);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> Handler<T> getHandler(Class<T> clazz) {
    return (Handler<T>) handlers.get(clazz);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> Handler<T> getHandlerFor(T t) {
    return getHandler((Class<T>) t.getClass());
}

public void run()    {
    addHandler(Foo.class, new FooHandler());
}

public <T> void handleMessage(T msg) {
    Handler<T> handler = getHandlerFor(msg);
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.execute(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer led me to type safe heterogeneous containers, relationships for generics types and whatnot! I'm a bit disappointed that it's impossible without wrapper methods and @SuppressWarnings however :<. Still, it works now, but I don't know if it's worth the hassle of introducing generics here.

Comment: The problem is how complicated do you want the generic syntax to be. ;) Its will check calls to addHandler, hetHandler and getHandlerFor are correct.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `execute()` takes a certain parameter type, that is more specific than `Object`.

However, in your `handleMessage()` method, the compiler doesn't know what type the parameter is. Suppose a case where `FooHandler` is registered for class `Bar` (which would be possible).

In that context `handler.execute(msg);` would actually result in `FooHandler#execute(Foo)` being called with a `Bar` argument, which would result in a `ClassCastException` (unless `Bar extends Foo`). Thus the compiler refuses to compile that code.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer that wasn't here but it should be - remove all of the generics syntax (i.e. remove all the `<?>`).  Then the parser will revert to JDK1.4 syntax and this will all work fine.